# Rest api caml query not returning field in ViewFields

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a CAML query that I am running through the REST api, the simple example below requests 2 fields - `FileLeafRef` and `CustomField`. Custom field is simple a text field, nothing special.

`CustomField` is returned whereas `FileLeafRef` is not.

If I run the same CAML via CSOM or the old WCF based services then `FileLeafRef` is returned...

```xml
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="FileRef" />
        <Value Type="Text">/SomeSite/SomeDocumentLibrary/SomeFile.txt</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
  <RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
    <FieldRef Name="CustomField" />
  </ViewFields>
</View>
```

I know I can use a `$select` querystring, but this is on an app that the user can specify any number of columns to retrieve and querystrings have a limit.

So is there something I am missing? Or does REST CAML act differently to the other two...

N.b this is against SharePoint Online

I should add this is being called via a post to an endpoint like `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/SomeSite/_api/web/lists(guid'listGuid')/getitems`

Comment: My test result is the same as yours, this should be by design.

Comment: I suppose the secondary question is then - if CAML allows you to specify ViewFields and REST accepts CAML, why does REST ignore the ViewFields specified by design?